# change all the column headings into select table.*

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

i have a query with 3 left joins, many wheres, and many more things.

The query work but php overwrite the values when into 2 tables are the same headings. ¿There are something similar to `Table1.* as Field11/21/31, Table2.* as Field12/22/23, TableN.* as Field1N/2N/3N`?

I found the tipic `Table1.Field1 as Name1, Table1.Field2 as Name2, Table2.Field1 as Name1_2,` ... But would be so long for my query.

Comment: Once you do this the less effort is supposed to put on in future.

Comment: The column alias (`as Name1`, etc) is the only way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ex:
     select first_name as fname, last_name as lname from table;

```
 this will output u as

     fname    lname
     rupesh   sawant
     jay      ghosh
```